# Migrate Mediawiki to Confluence using UWC java regex failing to match with |thumb on line

Tags: java, regex, mediawiki, confluence

I am trying to modify an existing java regex line to compensate for when a embedded picture in mediawiki is formatted with  "|thumb|none" at the end of the attachment name.  I am, not very familiar with regex and have been struggling to make this work.  When the program is run I need this "[[file:send-rec.jpg|thumb|none]]" to be turned into this "!send-rec.jpg!" but only when the regex detects that it is an image file (jpg|gif|bmp|png) there is a single line in the conversion file that I am able to modify:

```
Mediawiki.0402-re_file_to_images.java-regex=(?i)\[\[file:\s*([^\]\|\s]+)\s*\]\]{replace-with}!$1!
```

the "{replace-with}" is a placeholder.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Java that much, but the regex to capture a name from input such as [[file:send-rec.jpg|thumb|none]] can be done like this: `\[\[file:(.*?)\|.*`.

The name of the file should be in the first captured group (not accounting for the whole line match).

Here's an example using online tester: https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyhjqd0r

If you would provide more examples of the format, I will update the regex to be more specific.

**UPDATE**

Here is a regex that should work for all provided cases and only for .jpg / .gif / .bmp / .png:

`\[\[file:(.*?(?:\.jpg|\.gif|\.bmp|\.png))(?:\||]).*`

Explanations and tests: https://regex101.com/r/3lAH24/5

Comment: Thanks for the start, here are some more examples of how it can look:

Comment: [[File:EDI.png|thumb|304x304px|none]]  [[File:RMS Home screen.png|thumb|none]]  [[File:ClipCapIt-170110-133309.PNG]]  sometimes there is not aa "|" but the output still needs to be the file book ended with "!"

Comment: This should suffice: `\[\[file:(.*?)(?:\||])`. This should capture the file name in the first group, which then you can format with '!' around it.
Also make sure to search with 'case-insensitive' settings.

Please take a look here to check how it works: https://regex101.com/r/3lAH24/2

Comment: this seems to work, but can it be modified to only apply to images files with the .jpg .bmp .gif. .png file extensions?

Comment: tested further, the last example given is returning " !send-rec.bmp!thumb|none]]"  when replace is"!$1!"

Comment: I've updated the question to apply only for those formats.

Comment: Also sorry for that, the updated version should replace correctly.

Comment: this worked great all the way up until this example: '(?i)\[\[file:(.*?(?:\.jpg|\.gif|\.bmp|\.png))(?:\||]).*' applied to this: "[[File:INNER PACK LLBEAN LABEL EXAMPLE.docx|frameless]][[File:LL Bean -1.JPG|200px]] [[File:LLBean-2.JPG|200px]] [[File:LLBean-4.JPG|200px]] [[File:LLBean-5.JPG|200px]]"  I think it has to do with it not having line breaks to start the regex again but I am having issues trying to figure out how to insert anchors or something to have it not match inappropriately.

Comment: To make it work in single line I would make it like so: `\[\[file:([^|\]]+\.(?:jpg|gif|bmp|png))(?:\|.*?)*?]]` (https://regex101.com/r/3lAH24/6). You might also need the **global** flag when running the test, so that all of the links would be replaced inside the line.

Comment: is there a way to turn on the global inline with the regex eg: (?i) for case insensitive? it is working in the testing area when that is on but not when the line is being run.

Comment: Hm, I really can't find anything about how to set the global flag in java. Sorry, I'm not experienced in java, so I don't know how to help.